# HTML layout problems

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a problem with dividing a multicolumn layout in HTML. I have divided the page into two columns:

#### `inner1`

- Two rows.
- another_top1:fixed width,fixed hight
- response:fixed width,variable hight

#### `inner2`

- Two rows.
- another_top2:fixed width,variable hight
- another_below:fixed width,fixed hight

#### The problem:

When I try to divide `inner1` into two columns as in the following it works fine.

1. inner1
2. inner1_2

---

My `inner2` column `another_top2` data, appended below floating below `inner1_2` ends.

---

#### CSS:

```
#another_top1{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

#another_top2 {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

#outer{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
}

#inner1{
    float: left;
}

#inner1_2 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
.twoColumn #inner1 { width: 62%; }
.twoColumn #inner1_2 { display: none; }
.threeColumn #inner1 { width: 41%; }
.threeColumn #inner1_2 { width: 21%; }

#inner2{
    float: right;
    width: 39%;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you clarify the two columns that you entered in #inner_2? I can't make up from your code example how they are positioned, their sizes, etcetera.

Comment: What browser do you use when this happens?

Comment: inner1 has two column, either inner1 or inner1&inner1_2 ..But inner2 has only one column,and has two rows one by one

Comment: i use mozilla and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that the bug is caused by the float in the left column being wider than the column, pushing the content in the right column down. Make sure that the margins or paddings of inner1_2 do not make the box wider than the left column.

I would also recommend making #inner2 a fixed width, i.e. at least the width of your two columns. This way you make sure that the two columns would fit.

Also, check your doctype (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) to make sure that you are in standards mode, or correct for box model issues that might appear if you are in quirksmode.

Last, you can use Firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) or Xray (http://www.westciv.com/xray/) to check the dimensions of your divs, and then see if it extends beyond the left column.